# Email validation in C using glibc regex.h

Tags: c, regex, email-validation

**OK...got it to work with this regex:**

```
const char * reg_exp = "^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*@([a-z0-9])"
                       "(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?";
```

I don't yet how effective this expression is but I am happy to make some progress with this issue.

---

New to C pattern matching (regex).  I believe that I have tried to find an answer to my problem.

I am trying to get a simple email pattern matching to work in my registration module.  As I have it now coded, it fails to match a properly formatted email source on every pass.  I'm thinking, based on my very limited knowledge and understanding, that the following code should work if all other dependencies are met.  But, again, this just doesn't work.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Updated Example Code:

```
#include <regex.h>

regex_t regex;
... //other proc vars
int r, e;
unsigned char buf[RESBUF];
char *source = "johnnydoe@cloudnine.com";

const char *reg_exp1 = "/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@"
                       "([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|"
                       "edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])"
                       "|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i";
const char *reg_exp2 = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b";

char proc[] = "create_user";

r = regcomp(&regex,reg_exp2,REG_EXTENDED);
if(r) {
     sprintf(emessage,"REGEX COMPILE:Fail:%s:%s",proc,cgiRemoteAddr);
     log_proc(ebs->r,emessage,TXLOG);
     e = 1;
}
else {
     e = 0;
}
r = regexec(&regex,source,0,NULL,0); // source email
if(!r) {
     e = 0;
}
else
if(r == 1) {
     sprintf(emessage,"REGEX MATCH:Fail:%s",proc);
     log_proc(ebs->r,emessage,TXLOG);
     e = 1;
}
else {
     regerror(r,&regex,buf,100);
     sprintf(emessage,"REGEX MATCH:Fail:%s:%s",proc,buf);
     log_proc(ebs->r,emessage,TXLOG);
     e = 1;
}
regfree(&regex);
// Now evaluate e to determine success
if (!e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do it: `\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b` without the domain checking you are using. Read the description of it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

To add the domain checking the end would look something like what you have:

`\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.(ca|com|info|edu|...)\b`

**EDIT**

For simplicity try passing the pattern to the regcomp function directly. Stole this code from the POSIX example:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", 0);
    if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, "johnnydoe@cloudnine.com", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
            puts("Match");
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
            puts("No match");
    }
    else{
            regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            exit(1);
    }
```

Link: http://www.peope.net/old/regex.html

Comment: Thank you, Matthew for the response.  Still can't get a match.  Some background: The code is, of course, receiving the email address via ajax without problem.

Comment: This is well-tested implementation from that site (the only addition I made was to explicitly specify the lowercase chars). Can you double check your inputs are not wrapped with something (like quotes?) or some other issue with how they are being passed? Also try the original regex from the site. If it doesn't work when implemented as described the issue is not with the regex but somewhere else in your code. Also, please post your updated code once you have done all this.

Comment: As suggested, I reviewed Jan Goyvaerts's tutorial and updated the code as seen above.  However, even when using a procedure defined variable "char *source = johnnydoe@cloudnine.com" the call to regexec (as defined) fails to match the source.

Comment: I wish my C was less rusty - but looking at this again I think there may be an issue in how you are passing/setting your pointers/variables. Hopefully someone else can finish that thought who has worked with C more recently than 12 years ago.

Comment: @nhahtdh The link I posted has this to say about it: The official standard is known as RFC 2822. It describes the syntax that valid email addresses must adhere to. You can (but you shouldn't--read on) implement it with this regular expression: ... :) - I am cheating on the context of the comment a bit.

Comment: Matthew...even tried the direct parameter method.  Result is the same.  This is mind boggling to me.  I am more than fairly familiar with C and yet I feel like a 1st year grad student in Computer programming.  This should work being that it is so basic to the interface and piggybacks off of many of the examples presented online.

Comment: If you just execute the code I pasted does it work? What would happen if the regcomp library was missing or had an issue, would you receive the same error message? (My question being maybe your Regex is not being evaluated at all?)

Comment: The code you posted is what I used to model my code and it didn't work.  The regex was certainly being evaluated since it had logged.  The issue seem to have been resolved when I use the extend flag on regcomp and no extend on regexec.  I proofed this by playing around with these two flag configurations.  It's working now and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to make the error handling acceptable. Rather than a virtually useless `"REGEX MATCH:Fail:%s"` error message, you want error messages that describe what the problem was (`didn't start with a letter`, `missing '@' sign`, `multiple '@' characters`, `unrecognised top level domain`, etc). This is important for debugging (e.g. when you're overlooked something), and possibly even more important if user input (and feedback for bad user input) is involved.

Once the error handling is acceptable you'll have lots of small/trivial regular expressions that are a lot easier to understand and maintain and verify. It will be more code, but it will be good code rather than gibberish.

The next step is to improve the code more by replacing those small/trivial regular expressions with simpler/faster checks that don't use regular expressions at all. Once all the regular expressions are gone you know that you're using regular expressions properly. :-)

Comment: I think checking for specific issues might be overkill for things with a well known format like an email address.

Comment: I agree with you, Matthew.  I am trying to just get the regex to first work with the proper email format before begin to step into stricter methods.

Answer (score 0):

In C source, if you want the regex engine to see a backslash, you need two backslashes in your string literal.  Taking the simpler of your two:

```
const char *reg_exp2 = "\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b";
```

Of course, if the regex is read from a file, it only needs one backslash in the file; the crucial thing is that the backslash is in the string sent to the regex engine.

Hints:

1. When debugging, print the regex input string.
2. Pay attention to compiler warnings.  GCC 4.7.1 says of your second string:

   ```
   x.c:1:24: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\.' [enabled by default]
   ```

Comment: @Jonathan...I've tried using \\ escape sequence and that too failed.  However, I got it to work with: "^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?"

Comment: Hmmm...well the minimal change I made didn't fix your original `reg_exp2`'s insistence on upper-case letters in the email address; your working revision has all lower-case letters. And real email addresses are case-insensitive in fact. Regular expression notation is case-sensitive, so you probably need `[A-Za-z]` in your character classes (plus any other allowed characters). Your revised (but working) version looks as if it is somewhat too generous; it will allow names such as someone@somewhere as a valid email address (as well as someone@example.com).

Comment: There are two parts to debugging your regex: one, making sure the regex engine sees what you intend it to see, which was not happening because the `"\b"` notation was embedding a backspace into your regex (perfectly legitimate as part of a regex; just not as part of an email address).  The second part is ensuring that the regex you use is the one that matches the content you intend.  You have to do both tasks and get both right.  And a good test will have a suite of valid and invalid email addresses to run against.